# Implement multiple library versions with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, libraries, conflicting-libraries

I have two libraries, which both include by themself a different version of `com.android.billingclient:billing`; `1.2.2` and `2.0.3`

I need to use both libraries in my project, and if I *force* the use of one, one of both libraries won't compile anymore.

**How can I use both versions of `com.android.billingclient:billing` in my project, so that they don't conflict with each other?**

Comment: Use 2.0.3 it better as compared to 1.2.2 it's just an upgrade.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes

Comment: *How can I use both versions?* It is **not** possible.

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase to finding the solution to your problem is: `transitive dependency`. If you have 2 dependencies in your project that each have a sub-dependency (transitive dependency) on the same library but each uses different versions of that library then you'll need to tell one of them not to import that dependency.

Check out the discussion of this question in the Gradle Forums, I think it addresses your problem. It describes how to tell a dependency you declare not to automatically import a dependency it needs and will instead rely on you to explicitly declare the dependency or rely on the dependency being imported transitively:

[How do I exclude transitive dependencies of something I depend on](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991)

Comment: The real important information is: It's not possible to import the same library multiple times with different versions. When there are multiple occurrences of the same lib (identified by group and artifact id) with different versions in the dependency tree, the build system must decide which one to use.

Comment: @Peter agreed .

Comment: Thats my real problem... And why your answer may be helpful but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @SebastianSchneider I understood your problem as being you have declared two dependencies in Gradle, let's say dependency A and dependency B . You really only care about using libraries A and B but both of them have a sub-dependency to library C which you are not explicitly declaring in Gradle but library C is being pulled into your project by dependency A and B - both of which use different versions of library C...and because A and B use different versions of C it is causing a conflict...is that a correct summary of your problem?